# Best way to use conditional rendering in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am working on a React Native application. In the app, when the user signs in, an API call is made to the server to fetch the data using redux-saga. In the redux store, I am maintaining a boolean variable "fetchingData". It is set to 'true' once the API call is started and set to 'false' once the data is fetched or some error occurs. Now, I want to display a spinner when the data is being fetched, and a FlatList when the data is fetched. I know that I can do this by wrapping the return statement into an if-else condition. I suppose there must be some better way to do this. 
If someone can help me with this, please tell me a good way to achieve this conditional rendering in React Native. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. When the `render()` method gets called, appropriate component needs to be the returned based on the state.

```
render() {
    const isLoading = this.state.isLoading
    return isLoading ?
        <Spinner /> //return a spinner
        :
        <FlatList /> return a list with data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a pattern you use everywhere there are several ways to abstract the pattern out:

1. Creating a generic `<Loading />` component:

   ```
   class Loading extends React.Component {
     static defaultProps = {
       waitingElement: <Spinner />,
       renderedElement: null
     };

     render() {
       return this.props.loading ? this.props.waitingElement : this.props.renderedElement;
     }
   }

   // In some other component's `render`:        
   <Loading renderedElement={<component with=props />}, loading={this.state.isWaiting} />
   ```
2. Use a higher-order component to wrap your components:

   ```
   function withLoading(Component, spinner = <Spinner />) {
     return class extends Component {
       render() {
         if (this.props.loading) return spinner;
         return super.render();
       }
     };
   }

   // Some other file completely
   export default withLoading(class MyComponent {
     render() {
       return "Happy path only!";
     }
   });
   ```